# Кроссдоменный запрос с https на http с ответом обратно. И наоборот.

Tags: php, javascript, https, xmlhttprequest, cross-domain

Здравствуйте.
Сразу скажу, что данную проблему решил через Flash. Когда на сервер с https выложен специальный файл с разрешениями для флеша (crossdomain.xml), а сам флеш-ролик на сервере с http. Разумеется домены разные. Но **задачу упрощает то, что оба домена (сервера) "мои", т.е. есть возможность их настраивать и вносить изменения в работу**.
Но вообще хочется решить вопрос на JS через XHR. Или на худой конец через php (curl?).

Comment: с https **нельзя** слать запрос на http - браузер не позволит

Comment: Вообще можно. Но нужны дополнительные телодвижения. О том и вопрос.